# Grouping methods into categories Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

If I have several different groups of methods that I would like to use in `multiple classes`, which are all subclasses of `UIViewController`, would it be better style to include all of these methods into a `single category`, like `UIViewController+allGeneralMethods.h`

or have `multiple categories` like `UIViewController+Animations.h` , `UIViewController+GestureRecognizers` , `UIViewController+DateFormatters` , etc.

Comment: It depends. Are all your subclasses going to utilize all of the methods you've added? If not, break them up into different categories and import only what you need.

Comment: If some methods will be used only in 2-5 controllers then you should use inheritance not Categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your goal is to keep your code easy to investigate, use and modify.

Put all groups in one category if:

1. Most of your classes will use methods from all groups.
2. Each group includes only 1-2 methods.
3. Your development team is small and you do not expect that a lot of people will read your code (fragmented code easier to understand).

Put your code in several categories in other cases.